# Have any of the stories in 'Expedition to Earth' been made into films?

Tags: adaptations, expedition-to-earth

I read Arthur C. Clarke's **[*Expedition to Earth*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expedition_to_Earth)** when I was in elementary school although I struggled to understand it, it made a strong impression on me and I hope to find a good time to read it again.

I'm curious to know if any movies have been created based on the stories in this book.

Comment: While not in the Expedition to Earth collection, it should be noted that Clarke's _The Star_ was mangled into an episode of [The Twilight Zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Star_(The_Twilight_Zone)).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes!

- The story '[***Breaking Strain***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breaking_Strain)' was adapted into a film in 1994 under the title [*Trapped in Space*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108380/)

> 

- Elements of the stories **['*Encounter in the Dawn*'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encounter_in_the_Dawn)** and [***'The Sentinel'***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sentinel_(short_story)) were adapted into a film in 1968 under the title *[2001: A Space Odyssey](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0062622/)*

> 